# $K=\{v\in V:\|v\|\leqslant 1\}$ is compact $\iff\dim V<\infty$.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

$V$ is a vector space and metric $d: V\times V\to\Bbb R; \,(x,y)\mapsto\|x-y\|$ gives a entirely metric space.

I have to show that: $K=\{v\in V:\|v\|\leqslant 1\}\text{ is compact }\,\iff\dim V<\infty$.

My idea: For finitely many linearly independent vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k + 1$ we can construct a vector $v_k + 1$ which has a distance from $\operatorname{span}(\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\})$ ,which is $1$.

Maybe work with this or any other ideas how to prove this?

Comment: I haven't learned [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2291779/721644)     yet, but it might help.

Comment: If $V$ is infinite dimensional, construct a sequence in $V$ which has no convergent subsequence (Hint consider $x_n=\delta_n$)

Answer (score 1):

Use the rint of @Cheesecake. If $m=\text{dim}V < \infty$, take a sequence $(x_n)_n \in K$. Let's show that it has convergent subsequence. But by definition $||x_i|| \leq 1$ for all $i$, and each $x_i$ is written as a linear combination of the $ V $ base, say $x_i = \alpha^1_i e^1+ \ldots+\alpha^m_i e^m$. As the norms in finite dimension in $\mathbb{R}^n $(or $\mathbb{K}^n $) are equivalent,
$$1 \geq ||x_i|| =  ||\alpha^1_i e^1+ \ldots+\alpha^m_i e^m|| \geq c (\sum_{j=1}^{m}|\alpha^j_i|) = c||| (\alpha^1_i ,\ldots,\alpha^m_i) ||| $$ 
for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$. By Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem $((\alpha^1_i ,\ldots,\alpha^m_i))_{i=1}^{\infty}$ have a subsequence convergent, say $((\alpha^1_{i_k} ,\ldots,\alpha^m_{i_k}))_{k=1}^{\infty} \longrightarrow (\beta^1,\ldots, \beta^m)$. Then
$$|| \sum_{j=1}^{m} \alpha^j_{i_k}e^j - \sum_{j=1}^{m}\beta^je^j ||\leq \sum_{j=1}^{m} |\alpha^j_{i_k}-\beta^j| = \dfrac{1}{c}|||(\alpha^1_{i_k} ,\ldots,\alpha^m_{i_k})-(\beta^1,\ldots, \beta^m) ||| \longrightarrow 0$$
when $k$ goes to $\infty$. Hence $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_{i_k} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{m} \alpha^j_{i_k}e^j = \sum_{j=1}^{m}\beta^je^j.$ For the second part use the Hint of @Johnduck, or more precisely use the Riesz Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma 
and build a sequence that has no convergent subsequence with the following argument: choose any $ x_1 \in K $, consider the subspace generated by $ x_1 $ (it will be closed), by Riesz's Lemma, there is $ x_2 \in K $ such that $ || x_1-x_2 || \geq 1/2 $. Now consider $\text{Span}\{x_1,x_2\}$ by the Riesz Lemma, there is $ x_3 \in K $ with $ || x_1 - x_3 || \geq 1/2 $ and $ || x_2 - x_3 || \geq 1/2 $, as the dimension of $ V $ and infinite, this construction never stops.

Comment: wow how difficult ...thanks i would never get something like that

Comment: This is a result of Functional Analysis

Comment: you wont continue right? but thanks to this

Comment: Hello, the question is essentially asked! when you build the hint sequence, just argue that it has no convergent subsequence, because the distance between any two terms is greater than $1/2$. So $K$ cannot be compact in infinite dimension.